# Display Table From Database

Tags: php, codeigniter

On my database in codeigniter I have a table called store. I would like to be able to display my rows in table format on my view. And have it display in order by url

I have done the model and view but not sure what to put on the controller.

Error

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$data' (T_VARIABLE) in C:\Xampp\htdocs\codeigniter\codeigniter-cms\application\modules\admin\controllers\store\store.php on line 61
```

**Model**

```
<?php 

class Model_store extends CI_Model {

    public function getStores() {
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT DISTINCT * FROM " . $this->db->dbprefix. "store");
        return $query->row();
    }

}
```

**View** Updated

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
        <?php foreach ($stores as $row) { ;?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row['store_id'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['name'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['url'];?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Controller** Updated

```
public function index() {

$this->load->model('admin/store/model_store');

$stores = array();

$stores = $this->model_store->getStores();

$data['cancel'] = site_url('admin/dashboard');

return $this->load->view('store/store_list', $data);
}
```

Comment: Why aren't you passing store ids here `$this->model_store->getStores();`?

Comment: what is on C:\Xampp\htdocs\codeigniter\codeigniter-cms\application\modules\admin\controllers\store\store.php line - 61 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restructured whole of your code. Kindly check,

**Model:**

```
<?php 

class Model_store extends CI_Model 
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }    

    public function getStores($store_ids) 
    {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->distinct();
        $this->db->where_in('store_id', $store_ids);
        $query = $this->db->get($this->db->dbprefix."store");

        if($query->num_rows > 0)
            return $query->result();
        return false;
    }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
class Store extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('admin/store/model_store');
    }

    public function index() 
    {
        $store_ids = array('1','2','3');      // Pass your store ids here
        $data['store'] = $this->model_store->getStores($store_ids);
        $data['cancel'] = site_url('admin/dashboard');

        $this->load->view('store/store_list', $data);
    }
}
```

**View:**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
        <?php foreach ($store as $row) { ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row->store_id; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row->name; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row->url ;?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php } ?>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

**What changes did:**

1) Passed `store_ids` from `Controller` to `Model`.
2) Used `Active Records` instead of `Raw SQL Queries`.
3) Returned `result()` instead on `row()`. Difference is `result()` returns an array of objects, or an empty array on failure wheareas `row()` returns a single result row.
4) Syntax error in `foreach` loop.

Comment: How to get it order by url?

Comment: Its Ok now but just come across couple errors `
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Missing argument 1 for Model_store::getStores(), called in C:\Xampp\htdocs\codeigniter\codeigniter-cms\application\modules\admin\controllers\store\store.php on line 61 and defined

Filename: store/model_store.php

Line Number: 5
`

Comment: and second error 
`A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: store_id

Filename: store/model_store.php

Line Number: 8`

Comment: Yes, follow what I did above. These errors will not come.

Comment: don't want to have to type in '1' '2''3'

Comment: From where are you getting the store ids? Is it coming from URL? If yes, can you show me the URL.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60687/discussion-between-user3659372-and-parag-tyagi).

Answer (score 0):

```
  There few issues are in your code :

  1. $data is not declared before use [ $data=array() ]
  2. When getStores(); called no store id is been passed which will cause error in model.
  3. In View there is no existence of $query so you cant make loop of it to show. 
     You should use $store of controller $data["store"] which is receiving the data from 
     model.

   Hope you can understand it and make the rectifications to run it properly. Please let me know if need any further help.
```

Comment: Do you have example of what model should be and controller and view?

Comment: I updated post now just get  `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'endforeach' (T_ENDFOREACH) in C:\Xampp\htdocs\codeigniter\codeigniter-cms\application\modules\admin\views\template\store\store_list.php on line 21`

Answer (score 0):

**In Model:**

```
$this->db->select("*");
if(!empty($store_id))
{
    $this->db->where("store_id",$store_id); //if where required at all      
}
$this->db->from($this->db->dbprefix."store");
```

**In Controller:**

```
$data['store'] = $this->model_store->getStores(); // send store id when required
$data['cancel'] = site_url('admin/dashboard');
$this->load->view('store/store_list', $data);
```

**In View:**

```
foreach($store as $st)
{
     echo $st["id"];//and print all 
}
```

Hope it will work for you and My answer helps you.